# How to avoid filename dialog using Printer.Print and Microsoft Print to PDF

Tags: vba, pdf, vb6

Is there any way to send a print to the "Microsoft Print to PDF" driver already sending the file name and the location that it will be saved when using Printer.Print?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible using Printer.Print because the file name must be supplied via StartDoc() in gdi32.dll and the Printer object makes that call for you so you have no chance to modify it.

The alternative is to do your printing via API calls from cradle to grave.